# minecraft crashed on world load

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, mods

I was playing everything alright then when i went to save the world it crashed to the launcher.I then tried to load my saved world up but it crashed.so I believed that it was a corrupted file now so i deleted the whole save then made another one,but it also crashed on building terrain.
Here is the crash log:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Why did you do that?

Time: 4/26/15 5:12 PM
Description: Unexpected error

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at codechicken.nei.WorldOverlayRenderer.render(WorldOverlayRenderer.java:42)
    at codechicken.nei.ClientHandler.renderLastEvent(ClientHandler.java:170)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.ASMEventHandler_161_ClientHandler_renderLastEvent_RenderWorldLastEvent.invoke(.dynamic)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.ASMEventHandler.invoke(ASMEventHandler.java:54)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:138)
    at net.minecraftforge.client.ForgeHooksClient.dispatchRenderLast(ForgeHooksClient.java:261)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.func_78471_a(EntityRenderer.java:1354)
    at com.kingrunes.somnia.Somnia.renderWorld(Somnia.java:149)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.func_78480_b(EntityRenderer.java:1015)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71411_J(Minecraft.java:990)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:887)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:134)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.kingrunes.somnia.server.ForgeEventHandler.onEntityConstructing(ForgeEventHandler.java:23)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.ASMEventHandler_225_ForgeEventHandler_onEntityConstructing_EntityConstructing.invoke(.dynamic)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.ASMEventHandler.invoke(ASMEventHandler.java:54)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:138)
    at net.minecraft.entity.Entity.<init>(Entity.java:179)
    at net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityItem.<init>(EntityItem.java:69)
    at codechicken.lib.render.RenderUtils.<clinit>(RenderUtils.java:44)
    ... 18 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at codechicken.nei.WorldOverlayRenderer.render(WorldOverlayRenderer.java:42)
    at codechicken.nei.ClientHandler.renderLastEvent(ClientHandler.java:170)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.ASMEventHandler_161_ClientHandler_renderLastEvent_RenderWorldLastEvent.invoke(.dynamic)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.ASMEventHandler.invoke(ASMEventHandler.java:54)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:138)
    at net.minecraftforge.client.ForgeHooksClient.dispatchRenderLast(ForgeHooksClient.java:261)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.func_78471_a(EntityRenderer.java:1354)
    at com.kingrunes.somnia.Somnia.renderWorld(Somnia.java:149)

-- Affected level --
Details:
    Level name: MpServer
    All players: 1 total; [EntityClientPlayerMP['TMC29'/240, l='MpServer', x=440.50, y=69.62, z=201.50]]
    Chunk stats: MultiplayerChunkCache: 195, 195
    Level seed: 0
    Level generator: ID 00 - default, ver 1. Features enabled: false
    Level generator options: 
    Level spawn location: World: (432,64,206), Chunk: (at 0,4,14 in 27,12; contains blocks 432,0,192 to 447,255,207), Region: (0,0; contains chunks 0,0 to 31,31, blocks 0,0,0 to 511,255,511)
    Level time: 418 game time, 418 day time
    Level dimension: 0
    Level storage version: 0x00000 - Unknown?
    Level weather: Rain time: 0 (now: false), thunder time: 0 (now: false)
    Level game mode: Game mode: creative (ID 1). Hardcore: false. Cheats: false
    Forced entities: 91 total; [EntitySkeleton['Skeleton'/129, l='MpServer', x=430.50, y=23.00, z=138.50], EntityCreeper['Creeper'/130, l='MpServer', x=430.00, y=23.00, z=137.41], EntityZombie['Zombie'/131, l='MpServer', x=426.97, y=45.00, z=169.50], EntityBat['Bat'/132, l='MpServer', x=414.25, y=48.06, z=182.44], EntityHorse['Horse'/133, l='MpServer', x=424.28, y=67.00, z=269.28], EntityHorse['Horse'/134, l='MpServer', x=431.06, y=66.00, z=268.28], EntityHorse['Horse'/135, l='MpServer', x=429.59, y=66.00, z=275.25], EntityHorse['Horse'/136, l='MpServer', x=427.84, y=66.00, z=275.03], EntityCreeper['Creeper'/140, l='MpServer', x=443.00, y=24.00, z=132.50], EntityCreeper['Creeper'/141, l='MpServer', x=433.50, y=23.00, z=137.50], EntityCreeper['Creeper'/142, l='MpServer', x=433.50, y=23.00, z=135.44], EntitySkeleton['Skeleton'/143, l='MpServer', x=436.94, y=44.00, z=181.56], EntitySkeleton['Skeleton'/144, l='MpServer', x=434.50, y=45.00, z=178.50], EntityHat['unknown'/400, l='MpServer', x=440.50, y=69.62, z=201.50], EntityZombie['Zombie'/145, l='MpServer', x=434.69, y=30.00, z=199.50], EntitySkeleton['Skeleton'/146, l='MpServer', x=433.84, y=30.00, z=199.50], EntityPig['Pig'/147, l='MpServer', x=447.97, y=68.00, z=210.94], EntityZombie['Zombie'/151, l='MpServer', x=453.50, y=18.00, z=139.50], EntityCreeper['Creeper'/152, l='MpServer', x=461.50, y=39.00, z=221.69], EntityCreeper['Creeper'/153, l='MpServer', x=463.38, y=41.00, z=223.09], EntityZombie['Zombie'/154, l='MpServer', x=456.91, y=38.00, z=220.53], EntityPig['Pig'/155, l='MpServer', x=455.50, y=68.00, z=215.50], EntityPig['Pig'/156, l='MpServer', x=453.84, y=69.00, z=219.16], EntityPig['Pig'/157, l='MpServer', x=449.50, y=68.00, z=215.50], EntitySpider['Spider'/158, l='MpServer', x=451.72, y=35.00, z=241.34], EntityZombie['Zombie'/159, l='MpServer', x=450.50, y=48.00, z=253.50], EntitySkeleton['Skeleton'/160, l='MpServer', x=451.50, y=48.00, z=253.50], EntitySkeleton['Skeleton'/161, l='MpServer', x=452.50, y=48.00, z=251.50], EntityHorse['Horse'/162, l='MpServer', x=461.50, y=68.00, z=250.50], EntityHorse['Horse'/163, l='MpServer', x=459.50, y=67.00, z=254.50], EntityHorse['Horse'/164, l='MpServer', x=460.13, y=67.00, z=253.13], EntityHorse['Horse'/165, l='MpServer', x=457.59, y=69.00, z=247.09], EntityPig['Pig'/166, l='MpServer', x=457.22, y=67.00, z=263.78], EntityPig['Pig'/167, l='MpServer', x=458.84, y=67.00, z=262.53], EntityPig['Pig'/168, l='MpServer', x=458.50, y=67.00, z=261.03], EntityPig['Pig'/169, l='MpServer', x=455.44, y=66.00, z=261.19], EntitySkeleton['Skeleton'/173, l='MpServer', x=467.50, y=39.00, z=210.50], EntitySkeleton['Skeleton'/174, l='MpServer', x=468.72, y=36.00, z=218.16], EntityCreeper['Creeper'/175, l='MpServer', x=470.06, y=39.00, z=212.41], EntitySkeleton['Skeleton'/176, l='MpServer', x=470.50, y=38.00, z=211.50], EntityHorse['Horse'/177, l='MpServer', x=466.00, y=70.00, z=252.41], EntitySkeleton['Skeleton'/180, l='MpServer', x=493.97, y=15.00, z=140.47], EntityBat['Bat'/181, l='MpServer', x=482.75, y=16.06, z=141.16], EntitySpider['Spider'/182, l='MpServer', x=484.19, y=23.00, z=130.16], EntityBat['Bat'/183, l='MpServer', x=490.47, y=19.16, z=134.03], EntityBat['Bat'/185, l='MpServer', x=481.94, y=17.22, z=146.75], EntityZombie['Zombie'/186, l='MpServer', x=489.91, y=21.00, z=183.53], EntityHorse['Horse'/187, l='MpServer', x=486.72, y=63.00, z=212.75], EntityHorse['Horse'/188, l='MpServer', x=481.50, y=64.00, z=212.50], EntityHorse['Horse'/189, l='MpServer', x=480.13, y=64.00, z=212.13], EntityItem['item.item.leather'/190, l='MpServer', x=480.66, y=64.13, z=211.50], EntityBat['Bat'/191, l='MpServer', x=488.22, y=36.00, z=237.59], EntityHorse['Horse'/192, l='MpServer', x=488.09, y=70.00, z=235.69], EntityHorse['Horse'/193, l='MpServer', x=493.28, y=80.00, z=237.22], EntityHorse['Horse'/194, l='MpServer', x=491.56, y=80.00, z=238.44], EntityHorse['Horse'/195, l='MpServer', x=489.88, y=78.00, z=240.22], EntityCreeper['Creeper'/202, l='MpServer', x=509.50, y=27.00, z=123.50], EntitySkeleton['Skeleton'/203, l='MpServer', x=496.50, y=16.00, z=136.50], EntityZombie['Zombie'/204, l='MpServer', x=510.50, y=48.00, z=191.50], EntitySpider['Spider'/205, l='MpServer', x=503.66, y=47.00, z=206.44], EntityHorse['Horse'/206, l='MpServer', x=499.91, y=66.00, z=278.50], EntityHorse['Horse'/207, l='MpServer', x=502.00, y=67.00, z=278.50], EntityZombie['Zombie'/208, l='MpServer', x=512.44, y=11.00, z=176.84], EntityCreeper['Creeper'/211, l='MpServer', x=517.97, y=50.00, z=182.50], EntityCreeper['Creeper'/91, l='MpServer', x=368.63, y=23.00, z=149.94], EntitySkeleton['Skeleton'/92, l='MpServer', x=372.50, y=25.00, z=151.50], EntitySkeleton['Skeleton'/93, l='MpServer', x=376.50, y=25.00, z=147.50], EntityBat['Bat'/94, l='MpServer', x=364.75, y=17.03, z=161.25], EntityZombie['Zombie'/95, l='MpServer', x=373.78, y=27.00, z=164.78], EntityZombie['Zombie'/96, l='MpServer', x=373.50, y=28.00, z=168.50], EntityZombie['Zombie'/97, l='MpServer', x=373.88, y=32.00, z=224.59], EntityBat['Bat'/98, l='MpServer', x=381.50, y=34.44, z=226.16], EntityCow['Cow'/99, l='MpServer', x=375.50, y=69.00, z=255.50], EntityCow['Cow'/100, l='MpServer', x=373.50, y=69.00, z=252.50], EntityCow['Cow'/101, l='MpServer', x=373.78, y=70.00, z=249.69], EntityCow['Cow'/102, l='MpServer', x=374.50, y=70.00, z=257.50], EntityZombie['Zombie'/104, l='MpServer', x=398.50, y=48.00, z=181.50], EntityCreeper['Creeper'/105, l='MpServer', x=396.50, y=48.00, z=182.50], EntityCreeper['Creeper'/106, l='MpServer', x=390.50, y=30.00, z=228.50], EntityHorse['Horse'/107, l='MpServer', x=391.50, y=69.00, z=270.34], EntityHorse['Horse'/108, l='MpServer', x=390.06, y=69.00, z=272.19], EntityClientPlayerMP['TMC29'/240, l='MpServer', x=440.50, y=69.62, z=201.50], EntityCreeper['Creeper'/113, l='MpServer', x=407.16, y=24.00, z=244.22], EntityItem['item.item.sulphur'/114, l='MpServer', x=400.25, y=42.13, z=241.53], EntityBat['Bat'/115, l='MpServer', x=414.75, y=48.91, z=245.75], EntityEnderman['Enderman'/116, l='MpServer', x=406.50, y=41.00, z=271.38], EntityEnderman['Enderman'/117, l='MpServer', x=410.56, y=42.00, z=271.09], EntitySkeleton['Skeleton'/118, l='MpServer', x=404.69, y=41.00, z=271.72], EntitySkeleton['Skeleton'/121, l='MpServer', x=414.50, y=45.00, z=281.50], EntitySkeleton['Skeleton'/122, l='MpServer', x=411.50, y=45.00, z=278.50], EntityZombie['Zombie'/123, l='MpServer', x=403.06, y=39.00, z=280.53]]
    Retry entities: 0 total; []
    Server brand: fml,forge
    Server type: Integrated singleplayer server
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.multiplayer.WorldClient.func_72914_a(WorldClient.java:373)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71396_d(Minecraft.java:2433)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:916)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:134)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.10
    Operating System: Windows 8.1 (amd64) version 6.3
    Java Version: 1.8.0_25, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 245907640 bytes (234 MB) / 557776896 bytes (531 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 29, tallocated: 77
    FML: MCP v9.05 FML v7.10.85.1230 Minecraft Forge 10.13.2.1230 45 mods loaded, 45 mods active
    mcp{9.05} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    FML{7.10.85.1230} [Forge Mod Loader] (forge-1.7.10-10.13.2.1230.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    Forge{10.13.2.1230} [Minecraft Forge] (forge-1.7.10-10.13.2.1230.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    CodeChickenCore{1.0.4.29} [CodeChicken Core] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    NotEnoughItems{1.0.3.74} [Not Enough Items] (NotEnoughItems-1.7.10-1.0.3.74-universal.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    SomniaCore{1.3.1.23} [SomniaCore] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    OpenModsCore{0.7.1} [OpenModsCore] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    battlegear2{1.0.7.0} [Mine & Blade Battlegear 2 - Bullseye] (1.7.10-MB_Battlegear2-Bullseye-1.0.7.0.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    furnace3d{1.2.0} [Furnace 3D] (3D-Furnace-Mod-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    gender{1.0.1} [Gender] ([1.7.10]Gender-1.0.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    test{1.0} [test] (Arrow-Marker-Mod-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    BiblioCraft{1.7.3} [BiblioCraft] (BiblioCraft-Mod-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    CraftHeraldry{1.1.3} [CraftHeraldry] (CraftHeraldry 1.1.3.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    DamageIndicatorsMod{3.2.0} [Damage Indicators] (Damage-Indicators-Mod-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    DynamicLights{1.3.7} [Dynamic Lights] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    DynamicLights_onFire{1.0.4} [Dynamic Lights Burning Entity Module] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    DynamicLights_creepers{1.0.4} [Dynamic Lights Creeper Module] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    DynamicLights_dropItems{1.0.7} [Dynamic Lights EntityItem Module] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    DynamicLights_entityClasses{1.0.1} [Dynamic Lights Entity Light Module] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    DynamicLights_mobEquipment{1.0.7} [Dynamic Lights Mob Equipment Light Module] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    DynamicLights_flameArrows{1.0.0} [Dynamic Lights Fiery Arrows Light Module] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    DynamicLights_floodLights{1.0.1} [Dynamic Lights Flood Light] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    DynamicLights_otherPlayers{1.0.7} [Dynamic Lights OtherPlayers Light Module] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    DynamicLights_thePlayer{1.1.3} [Dynamic Lights Player Light Module] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    exnihilo{1.37} [Ex Nihilo] (Ex-Nihilo-1.37.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    iChunUtil{4.1.3} [iChunUtil] (iChunUtil-4.1.3.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    Hats{4.0.1} [Hats] (Hats-4.0.1.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    HopperDuctMod{1.3.2} [Hopper Ducts] (hopperductmod-1.7.10-1.3.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    radixcore{1.3.4} [RadixCore] (RadixCore-1.7.10-1.3.4-universal.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    mca{4.1.5} [Minecraft Comes Alive] (MCA-1.7.10-4.1.5-universal.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    cfm{3.4.7} [§9MrCrayfish's Furniture Mod] (MrCrayfishFurnitureModv3.4.7(1.7.10).jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    OpenMods{0.7.1} [OpenMods] (OpenModsLib-1.7.10-0.7.1.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    OpenBlocks{1.4.1} [OpenBlocks] (OpenBlocks-1.7.10-1.4.1.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    harvestcraft{1.7.10g} [Pam's HarvestCraft] (Pam's HarvestCraft 1.7.10h.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    placeableitems{1.4} [Placeable Items Mod] (placeableitems-1.4.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    ragdollCorpses{0.12} [Ragdoll Corpses] (ragdollCorpses-0.12 for 1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    RopesPlus{1.6.3} [Ropes+] (Ropes-Plus-Mod-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    SlimevoidLib{2.0.4.7} [Slimevoid Library] (SlimevoidLibrary-2.0.4.7.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    Somnia{-au} [Somnia] (Somnia-1.4.1.23.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    saohud{v1.0} [Sword Art Online HUD] (Sword-Art-Online-HUD-Mod-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    Waila{1.5.3} [Waila] (Waila-Mod-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    Sync{4.0.0} [Sync] (Sync-Mod-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    rafradek_wallpaint{1.1.2} [Wall Painter] (Wall-Painter-Mod-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    WirelessRedstoneCore{1.8.0.0} [Wireless Redstone] (WirelessRedstoneCore-1.8.0.0.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    zipline{1.0} [Zipline] (Zipline-Mod-1.7.10.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    OpenModsLib class transformers: [stencil_patches:FINISHED],[movement_callback:FINISHED],[map_gen_fix:FINISHED],[gl_capabilities_hook:FINISHED],[player_render_hook:FINISHED]
    Stencil buffer state: Function set: GL30, pool: internal, bits: 8
    Launched Version: 1.7.10
    LWJGL: 2.9.1
    OpenGL: Intel(R) HD Graphics 2500 GL version 4.0.0 - Build 10.18.10.3958, Intel
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Anisotropic filtering is supported and maximum anisotropy is 16.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.

    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: [Battle-Gear-2-Pack-1.8.zip]
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Anisotropic Filtering: Off (1)
```

Basically, what caused my game to crash? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a modded Minecraft crash.  We only support vanilla Minecraft crashes.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is because of an error rendering an entity:

```
at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.func_78471_a(EntityRenderer.java:1354)
at com.kingrunes.somnia.Somnia.renderWorld(Somnia.java:149)
```

And within the list of entities, we spot this:

```
EntityHat['unknown'/400, l='MpServer', x=440.50, y=69.62, z=201.50]
```

It appears your Hats mod is causing issues. The game attempts to render an entity in the world (in this case, your player's hat), but fails and crashes the game. Try the following procedure:

- Uninstall the Hats mod
- Start Minecraft and reload the affected world
- Reinstall the Hats mod and try reloading the world again

If this doesn't work, you could try...

- Using a different version of the Hats mod
- Modifying the mod's configurationn file, usually located in the config folder in the .minecraft folder (A tutorial on finding this folder can be found [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/.minecraft?cookieSetup=true)) (Note: the mod's config file will most likely be named "Hats" or something easily identifiable)

But if all else fails, you may just have to play without the mod.

Comment: thanks so much for that i thought the save corrupted my whole system!anyways thank you very much for this!